# filtering data in a flat file with millions of records

Tags: perl, awk, filtering

I have a gzipped file `tradedata.txt.gz` which contains millions of records. this file has about 50 fields separated by `|`. The 45th field can contain values such as `0000`, `0002`, `0003`, `0004` and blank value(null).  I want to filter the file and get those rows with value 0000,0002 and blank values only.  I want to do this in the fastest way using `awk`, `perl`, or any other language.

For example, the data looks like this (I am only displaying few fields for illustration purposes).

```
abc|234|test|0000|test2|1
abc|2343|test1|0002|test2|1
abc|2345|test3|0004|test2|1
abc|2346|test4|0004|test2|1
abc|2347|test5|0003|test2|1
abc|2348|test6||test2|1
abc|234|test|0003|test2|1
```

The results after filtering the data should be:

```
abc|234|test|0000|test2|1
abc|2343|test1|0002|test2|1
abc|2348|test6||test2|1
```

As you can see, I am only pulling records with value 0000,0002 and blank.
Can someone help with this request using awk, perl or anything other language that does it the fastest way?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i am an oracle developer. i tried using oracle but oracle loading tool is not powerful enough to have complex filter. a friend of mine told me that this could be done in unix using awk, perl etc but i dont know those languages.

Comment: Then I am afraid you are asking in the wrong place. Stack Overflow is about helping you - as a programmer - figure out problems and solve them. It is not about writing code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'|' '$4=="0000"||$4=="0002"||$4==""' file
abc|234|test|0000|test2|1
abc|2343|test1|0002|test2|1
abc|2348|test6||test2|1
```

Change `$4` to `$45` for your actual input file.

Using `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane 'print if grep $F[3] eq $_, ("0002", "0000", "")' file
abc|234|test|0000|test2|1
abc|2343|test1|0002|test2|1
abc|2348|test6||test2|1
```

Change `$F[3]` to `$F[44]` for your actual input file.

**Update:**

As [hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204955/filtering-data-in-a-flat-file-with-millions-of-records/30205150#comment48515899_30205150) mentioned in the comment below, you can try the following if existing solution aren't quick enough:

`perl -F'\|' -lane 'print if $F[3] =~ /\A(?:0002|0000|)\z/' file`

Comment: `print if $F[3] =~ /\A(?:0002|0000|)\z/` is likely to be faster than your `grep`, possibly enough to matter for 45 million records.

Comment: Thanks @hobbs for an alternate solution. I wasn't sure if regex would have been any quicker. But I'll include your comment in the answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: I benchmarked it, and it is faster. The overhead of the regex engine is outweighed by the fact that the `grep` has to call `eq` three times on every row, and do more stack manipulation — checking the regex is a single op per line :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is all in one test

```
awk -F'|' '$4~/^(000(0|2)|)$/' file
abc|234|test|0000|test2|1
abc|2343|test1|0002|test2|1
abc|2348|test6||test2|1
```

Comment: @EdMorton On a large random generated file this `awk -F'|' '$1~/(000[02])/'` gave  `37.3s` and this `awk -F'|' '$1~/(000(0|2))/'` gave `35.8s`.  So not much difference, but agree that  `[02]` is more readable.